# how can i run monodroid in vs 2010?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mono, android-ndk

i downloaded Monodroid: http://monodroid.net/Installation   but i write 2 simple project 2 days ago. But i press f5 to run . i face to face

#### This beta version has expired. Please upgrade to a newer beta to help us test the latest code

How can i run it?

Comment: That sounds like a question for the monodroid discussion list... in that it is tied to a very specific build of a pre-release product.

Comment: I think you should upgrade to a new beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My gut says that the beta version you are using has expired.  You should upgrade to a newer beta.

http://go-mono.com/monodroid-download/

Comment: How am I supposed to be able to justify SO as a valuable, serious Developer resource in the workplace when you keep making me LOL. ;)